# What is the best way for calculating running total?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my SQL Query which i run for March  and it runs flawlessly but when i run it for April it is just running and running

However if I avoid running total, it works great again.

Please help if the syntax is wrong or if there is an alternative to the design.

```
;
WITH T as (
SELECT 0 as seq,0 as [Ref No],'' as [Type],0 as [JV NO] ,0 as[MONTH],DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,'20140401')-1,0) as [Date],0 as [Chequ No.],DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0, '20140401')-1,0) as [Due Date],'Transferred' as [Discription],'' as[Payee],
0 as [Debit],  -- ANA DÖVÝZ BORÇ
0 as [Credit],  -- ANA DÖVÝZ ALACAK
SUM([#msg_S_0103\T]) as [Amount] -- ANA DÖVÝZ TUTAR
,dbo.fn_CariHarEvrTipUzun(cha_evrak_tip) AS [msg_S_0094] 
,cha_RECno
,cha_RECid_RECno
From dbo.fn_HamCariFoy ( N'0',2, N'01',1,null,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,'20140401')-1,0),0,'','' )
inner join CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI on CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI.cha_RECno = [msg_S_0088]
GROUP BY [#msg_S_1712],[msg_S_0112],cha_evrak_tip ,cha_RECno
,cha_RECid_RECno
union all
Select TOP 100 Percent ROW_NUMBER ()  over (order by cha_tarihi ) as seq,msg_S_0091 as [Ref No],

 msg_S_0003 as [Type],[JV NO],[MONTH],msg_S_0089 as [Date],
 case  ISNUMERIC(#msg_S_0093) when 1 then
 CONVERT(int, ISNULL(NULLIF (#msg_S_0093, ''), 0))
else 0
end as [Chequ No.],
msg_S_0098 as [Due Date],#msg_S_0085 as [Discription],[Payee],
sum([msg_S_0101\T]) as 'Debit',sum([msg_S_0102\T]) as 'Credit',
(sum([msg_S_0101\T])- sum([msg_S_0102\T]))AS 'Amount'
,dbo.fn_CariHarEvrTipUzun(cha_evrak_tip) AS [msg_S_0094] 
,cha_RECno
,cha_RECid_RECno
from dbo.fn_CariFoy (N'0',2,N'01',1,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0, '20140401')-1,0), '20140401',     '20140430',0,N'')
inner join CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI on CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI.cha_RECno = [msg_S_0088] 
group by msg_S_0091,msg_S_0003,msg_S_0089,#msg_S_0093,#msg_S_0085,[MONTH],msg_S_0098          ,cha_RECno,cha_tarihi
,cha_RECid_RECno
,[JV NO],[Payee] ,cha_evrak_tip
order by convert(int,#msg_S_0093)
)

**SELECT * ,(SELECT SUM(Amount)  from T as b
 Where b.seq <= a.seq )as [Remaining Balance] from T a
order by Date**
```

What is the best way for calculating running total? How can I optimize the above query?

Comment: You know what issue is! your query is getting inside loop, Please provide some data.

Comment: How can it run flawlessly when you remove SELECT and leave only WITH? Syntax errors would be reported by SQL Server engine.

Comment: Actually you are calculating running total for each record. For second record -> 1st record + 2nd record, for third record -> 1st record + 2nd record + 3rd record...etc etc. It will definitely become slow. It is noticed that even though cursor have performance issues, cursors will be fast to calculate running total than the above.  @Tanveer Khan

Comment: Can you share actual query plan?

Comment: Use this link which explains the best way to get running total

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Comment: @VDohnal It works fine for some other month. **Select statement is at the end** if you see it.

Comment: @AK47 It is not going into loop as it is running for the month of March.

Comment: @SarathAvanavu I will study cursors now. Thank you

Comment: @SarathAvanavu Sir can you please make the necessary change in my query to accommodate cursor, I am actually comparatively new in sql and not a developer by academic background.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing `CURSOR` as Tanveer Khan suggested to do for him.

Just insert the result from `CTE` to a temporary table avoiding the calculation of Running Total.

```
;WITH T AS
(
   -- Your queries 
)
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM T
```

Now you need to select the result from the above temporary table to find the running total with `CURSOR`

```
DECLARE @Seq INT
DECLARE @Amount NUMERIC(20,2)
DECLARE @Previous@Amount NUMERIC(20,2)=0

-- Here you declare which all columns you need to loop in Cursor
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Seq,Amount
FROM #TEMP
ORDER BY Seq;

OPEN CUR

-- Loop starts from here and selects each Seq and Amount of each record in each loop 
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR 
INTO @Seq,@Amount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    UPDATE #TEMP SET RUNNINGTOTAL = @Amount + @Previous@Amount
    WHERE Seq = @Seq

    -- Saves previous row's cumiliative total in variable
    SET @Previous@Amount =  @Amount + @Previous@Amount

    -- Fetches next record and increments the loop
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR 
    INTO @Seq,@Amount
END 

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;
```

Now the Running Total will be saved in a column in temporary table and you can select from it using

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

Please feel free to ask for any doubts.
Best wishes.

Comment: Did this help you? @Tanveer Khan